# When updating Collection Items for a DataGrid Asynchronously why does the data disappear?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that is bound to a DataGridCollectionView which is using an Observable Collection.  The collection contains about 650+ items with around 20 columns.  Every 60 seconds a new collection of data is received.  That data is compared against the existing collection and then items Added, Removed, and Updated as needed.  For the update I am doing the following:

```
private async void LoadData()
    {
        await RefreshData(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100), cts.Token);
    }

private async Task RefreshData(TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // Get the writable properties for the ContingencyViewModel 
        var writableProperties = typeof(ContingencyViewModel).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
            .Where(p => p.CanWrite);

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var list = viewModel.Items;
            var cvs = GetItems();  // Service call that gets the updated collection
            var existingIds = list.Select(s => s.UniqueId).Distinct().ToList();
            var sourceIds = cvs.Select(s => s.UniqueId).Distinct().ToList();

            var toAdd = sourceIds.Except(existingIds).ToList();
            var toRemove = existingIds.Except(sourceIds).ToList();
            var toUpdate = existingIds.Intersect(sourceIds).ToList();

            var itemsToAdd = cvs.Where(x => toAdd.Contains(x.UniqueId)).ToList();
            var itemsToRemove = list.Where(x => toRemove.Contains(x.UniqueId)).ToList();
            var itemsToUpdate = list.Where(x => toUpdate.Contains(x.UniqueId)).ToList();

                // Add new items
                foreach (ItemViewModel item in itemsToAdd)
                {
                    list.Add(item);
                }

                // Remove dropped items
                foreach (ItemViewModel item in itemsToRemove)
                {
                    list.Remove(item);
                }

                // Update existing items
                foreach (ItemViewModel item in itemsToUpdate)
                {
                    // Get a reference to the Updated Item
                    var source = cvs.First(x => x.UniqueId == item.UniqueId);

                    // This works but locks the UI for a little bit
                    this.UpdateItem<ItemViewModel>(source, item, writableProperties);

                   // This also works but all the results in my grid disappear when I scroll or resize screen.  To get them back I have to actually Expand and Collapse groups.
                    /*
                    Action d = delegate()
                    {                        
                        this.UpdateItem<ItemViewModel>(source, item, writableProperties);
                    };

                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(d, DispatcherPriority.Normal, token);
                    */

                } 

                if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            if (interval > TimeSpan.Zero)
                await Task.Delay(interval, token);
        }
    }

private void UpdateItem<T>(T source, T target, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties)
    {
        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            var value = p.GetValue(source);
            p.SetValue(target, value);
        }  
    }
```

Doing a straight update lags the UI as I expected, however trying to do it from another thread seems to cause the data to disappear whenever you scroll or resize the window.  By disappear I mean the rows are there but they are empty.  The only way to get it back is to collapse and expand a group.  I've even tried putting refreshes in for the datasource (which seems like a bad idea to me because it would get called after every single field update).

Why does the data disappear on Async updates?  Is there a better or more appropriate way to do these kinds of updates on items bound to a datagrid?

Comment: You should call your update logic from the UI thread. Try `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(youraction)` when you are updating from an async event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know WPF follows STA architecture . So as a thumb rule all the updations should be done on the UI thread . You may use Dispatcher for the above scenario : 
You can read more about dispatcher [here](http://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/dispatcher-part-1/) and [here](http://adityaswami89.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/dispatcher-part-2/?relatedposts_hit=1&relatedposts_origin=46&relatedposts_position=1)

Ideally you can try something like :

```
ThreadStart start = delegate()
{
  // make your calls to the db

  Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                    new Action<object>(UpdateCollection), 
                    new object[] { myData });
};
new Thread(start).Start();

private void UpdateCollection(object data)
{
   //iterate your collection and add the data as needed
}
```

Comment: This does work.  It works better if I pass the entire collection of things to be updated rather than passing each item to be updated one at a time.  I had thought that this was what I was doing with the Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync.  I'm going to look up the difference between Invoke and InvokeAsync.  One other small change was that I had to call Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke to get the correct dispatcher for the UI thread.